# Have tkinter GUI Open up previously closed data when closed accidently

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a GUI with tkinter to have data display on a treeview and where the user can edit, remove, add, and save the treeview data. I have it to where the treeview is pulling yesterdays data
(using timedelta), but if the user or something accidently causes the application to close. How would I make the application open up with the data that they were working with instead of yesterdays data?

My treeview

```
def tree(self):
    self.tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self)

    self.tree1['columns'] = ("Testing Station", "Break_Lunch", "Teammate", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work", "Notes")

    self.tree1.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
    self.tree1.column('Testing Station', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
    self.tree1.column('Break_Lunch', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
    self.tree1.column('Teammate', anchor=CENTER, width=120)
    self.tree1.column('Start Date', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
    self.tree1.column('Agency', anchor=CENTER, width=120)
    self.tree1.column('Hours Work', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
    self.tree1.column('Notes', anchor=CENTER, width=120)

    self.tree1.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Testing Station', text='Station #', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Break_Lunch', text='Break--Lunch', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Teammate', text='Teammates', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Start Date', text='Start Date', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Agency', text='Agency', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Hours Work', text='Hours Work', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('Notes', text='Notes', anchor=CENTER)

    self.tree1.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=7, pady=10, padx=10)

    os.chdir('Csv Files')
    self.path2 = os.getcwd()

    with open("Testing A-Side " + self.yesterday.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + ".csv", newline='')as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        '''
        with open('A-side.csv', newline='')as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        '''
        for col in reader:
            station = col['Testing Station']
            b_l = col['Break_Lunch']
            name = col['Teammate']
            start = col['Start Date']
            agency = col['Agency']
            hw = col['Hours Work']
            note = col['Notes']
            self.tree1.insert('', 0, values=(station, b_l, name, start, agency, hw, note))


    self.parent2 = os.path.dirname(self.path2)
    os.chdir(self.parent2)
```

My save function

```
def saveSheet(self):
    os.chdir('Teammate Sheet')
    self.path = os.getcwd()

    self.excolumns = ["Testing Station", "Break_Lunch", "Teammates", "Start Date", "Agency", "Hours Work", "Notes"]#, "Production Total"]
    self.info = [self.tree1.item (item) ['values'] for item in self.tree1.get_children()]
    self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.info, columns=self.excolumns)
    self.df.to_excel("Testing A-Side " + self.today.strftime("%m" + '.' + "%d" + '.' + "%Y") + ".xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)

    self.parent = os.path.dirname(self.path)
    os.chdir(self.parent)
```

Comment: Save the information that the user inputted in the GUI and restore it when the user runs the program again.

Comment: You've posted far too much code for this question. Please create a [mcve]. If the question is about saving data, you don't need more than a widget or two to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `tkinter.ttk.Treeview` but you can save the state of the program to a file and restore it whenever the user runs the program again. Basically you need to create an autosave feature.

This is an example that works with `tkinter.Entry`

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os.path

def autosave(event):
    # Save the user's input in the autosave file
    with open("autosave.data", "w") as file:
        file.write(entry.get())

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
# Bind to the user pressing any/all keys
entry.bind("<KeyPress>", autosave)

# If the file exists read it and put the data in the entry
if os.path.isfile("autosave.data"):
    with open("autosave.data", "r") as file:
        entry.insert(0, file.read())

root.mainloop()
```

Without seeing your most of your code, there is no way of me giving you a proper answer but the idea is still the same. Save the state of the GUI (in the example it is the data in the entry) to a file. Whenever the program is run restore the data back into the GUI

Comment: I thought I had my code on there...My bad. It's up now tho.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data to a file somehow. The `json` package is pretty good for this. Create some data structure that describes all the internal data, dump it to a .json file whenever something changes, and add a button or something to allow the user to load the data from that .json file.